# How to roll back a conda installation with the following error message?

Tags: anaconda, conda

I am trying to roll back my conda installation to an earlier revision using the following command:

conda install --revision 1

However here is the error message I receive:

```
Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: failed

RemoveError: This operation will remove conda without replacing it with
another version of conda.
```

Comment: Is this is new installation? Otherwise, why roll back so far? Another strategy for reseting a base environment is to provide a minimal YAML (e.g., with only `conda` and `python` + version specified) then use `conda env update -n base --prune`. That effectively recreates **base** with only the necessities to install `conda`.

Comment: I had created the environment in a customized fashion meaning a very specific versions of a dozen packages can work together. The problem showed up when I attempted to update conda. I think it forced an updated on some of the packages. After the update took place, I could no longer run my script. Therefore, I needed to go back to version 1 of the environment which was specifically created for this set of packages. However, I don't know why I was getting the error message. I attempted multiple things with no success. Fortunately, I had a list of those packages in the original environment.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the environment and re-created it from scratch as nothing else seemed to work.

Comment: I'm confused now. So it wasn't the **base** environment after all? Note that no other environments should ever have the `conda` package installed - perhaps that was causing an issue?

Comment: True! that was the issue.